# Dynamic width of table div

Tags: html, css

I need to have a div construct with a `table`-display, while the first cell should be as wide as the content fit to it without linebreak. The second cell should take the rest of the width,

**html**

```
<div class="table full-width">
    <div class="table-cell">Cell 1 without br</div>
    <div class="table-cell">Cell 2 just the rest width</div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.full-width {
    width: 100%;
}
.table {
    display: table;
}
.table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `table`, `tr`, and `td`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly recommend *not* explicitly styling `<div>`s as table elements. Use the default HTML elements for that, or perhaps use more fluid formatting styles, such as `float`.

However, I suggest you use the more modern CSS3 [`flex-box`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), with its children style `flex-grow`. It gives you a lot more flexibility in situations like these.

```css
div.container {
  display: flex; 
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 20px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
div.shrink, div.grow {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  background-color: grey;
  flex-basis: auto;
}
div.shrink {
  flex-shrink: 1;
}
div.grow {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="shrink">
    This will shrink!
  </div>
  <div class="grow">
    This will grow!
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="table full-width">
    <div class="table-cell">Cell 1 without br</div>
    <div class="table-cell cell-wide">Cell 2 just the rest width</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.full-width {
    width: 100%;
}
.table {
    display: table;
}
.table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    white-space: pre;
}
.cell-wide {
  width: 100%
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o5m63gcc/)